# Passing data from a child component to a parent component (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child, react-component, react-state

I have a child component that has some states which change in value when you check or un-check some boxes; I want to be able to pass those state values to the parent component. I've tried a few things on the internet but nothing seem to work.

I've tried to (Parent Component File):

```
const ParentComponent = () => {

     const [ data, setData ] = useState();

     const childToParent = (childData) => {
          setData(childData);
     };

     return(
          <Child childToParent={childToParent} />
     );
}
```

and on the Child Component:

```
const ChildComponent = ({ childToParent }) => {

     const [ childData, setChildData ] = useState(false);

     const handleChange = () => {
          setChildData(!childData);
          childToParent(childData);
     };

     return(
          <div>
               <Checkbox value={childData} callback{() => handleChange()} />
          </div>
     );
}
```

Basically the problem is I dont get how to move data from a child component to a parent component.

Comment: Generally you want a uni-directional flow of data down the tree, so my fist instinct is that the parent should own the state

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing the implementation of `handleChange`, but it appears your child isn't even receiving the checkbox's value in the first place. You're using `useState` to hold the value, but not providing the `setChildData` capability to `handleChange`. That means `handleChange` will always be invoked with the current value.

Comment: React is built around the philosophy of parent to child data flow, only one directional.
and states are managed within the components However, I think what you are looking for is "Lifting  state up" solution. you have a quick look on thiis topic from react official doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: How can I change states of the parent component from the child component?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a [mcve] that illustrated the problem, or describe in what way this is failing to work.  Right now from your question we understand it "doesn't work", but we don't understand if that means nothing happens, or an error is shown, or if the child fails to update, or if nothing renders at all.  What you are describing tends to be relatively trivial, most idiomatically accomplished with "lifting state" as @RimonHabib describes, so it would be helpful to understand just what problem specifically you are facing.